# Using variables with sed but having escaping issues

Tags: sed

I'm trying to use sed to perform an inline search and replace but I think weird characters are causing issues.

My config.inc file contains 2 lines:

```
$GLOBALS['industry_id'] = '1';
yyyy
```

Something simple like this works and replaces yyyy with zzzz:

```
x="yyyy"
y="zzzz"
sed -i "s/${x}/${y}/" config.inc
```

But something like this doesn't work:

```
x="$GLOBALS['industry_id'] = '1';"
y="$GLOBALS['industry_id'] = '3';"
sed -i "s/${x}/${y}/g" config.inc
```

Do I need to escape the characters like $ [ ] ' ; (though this doesn't work either):

```
x="\$GLOBALS\[\'industry_id\'\] = \'1\'\;"
y="\$GLOBALS\[\'industry_id\'\] = \'3\'\;"
sed -i "s/${x}/${y}/g" config.inc
```

What am I missing?

Thanks
Chris

**UPDATE:** Ok thanks to pfnuesel the following works:

```
x="\\\$GLOBALS\\['industry_id'\\] = '1';"
y="$GLOBALS['industry_id'] = '3';"
sed -i "s/${x}/${y}/g" config.inc
```

Comment: There's still an escape character missing: `y="\$GLOBALS['industry_id'] = '3';"` (since the `$` has to be escaped in bash).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'$' has a special meaning in `bash` (parameter expansion), you'd need to escape it, i.e.

```
$ x="\$GLOBALS['industry_id'] = '1';"
```

Now you have

```
$ echo $x
> $GLOBALS['industry_id'] = '1';
```

But if you try the `sed` command, it will still not work, because `$` has also a special meaning in `sed` (end of line). Also the `[` and `]` have special meanings in `sed`, we need to escape them all. Since the escape character `\` also has a special meaning, we need to escape it as well.

```
$ x="\\\$GLOBALS\\['industry_id'\\] = '1';"
```

If we now do

```
$ echo $x
> \$GLOBALS\['industry_id'\] = '1';
```

i.e. one escape character before the special characters `$`, `[` and `]`.

Note that this is not necessary for `y`, since neither `$`, nor `[` or `]` have a special meaning in the string to be replaced (only in the string to be substituted).

Comment: I just tried the following and it didn't work:

`x='\$GLOBALS['industry_id'] = '1';'`
`y="$GLOBALS['industry_id'] = '3';"`
`sed -i "s/${x}/${y}/g" config.inc`